# How to insert whitespace in an string in Qt using RegEx

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I have a `QString` like `"(ram[3].available@=> 10,2,25 &( cpu.load <>   42,49 |qweds[-1].ee0 ~\"arab lllss\" ) )"` and I want to enter white space after each non-alphabetic character (i.e. `@` , `~`, `(` and etc.) then split the string. I tried [gSkinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) online tool and I found that I need to replace `\s*\W` with `$&` to have the white space between special characters and alphanumeric characters. But I don't know how I can implement it in Qt using `QregExp` and `QString`.

Basically what I want to do is:

```
QString smth = "(ram[3].available@=> 10,2,25 &( cpu.load <>   42,49 |qweds[-1].ee0 ~\"arab lllss\" ) )";
Qstring smth2 = smth.replace("\s*\W\", "hereIdunnoWhattoPut");
QStirngList l = smth2.split(" ",QString::SkipEmptyParts);
qDebug() << l;
//( "(" , "ram" , "[" , "3" , "]" , "." , "available" , "@" , "=" , ">" , "10".... )
```

Comment: Just forget about regexps: iterate the string, [check](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qchar.html#isLetterOrNumber) if the symbol is alphabetic and act accordingly.

Comment: That seems to solve it, then I need to `insert` a space in the index of char...I'm trying it out.

Comment: Yes, and you should update your iterators (position counter) carefully.